# Wil this work, how can i compare a string array elements to a predefined string and copy to a new array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

Wil this work, how can i compare a string array elements to a predefined string and copy to a new array.

```
String element={"France","Germany","USA","France","Italy"}
String finalelement[]= null;
String compareelement = "France";
int l =elements.length;
int i1 = 0;
for(int i=0; i<l; i++)
{
//comparing the elements
    if((compareelement.equals(element[i])))
        {
//assigning the array element
            finalelement[i1]=element[i];   
            i1++;
        }
}
```

Comment: "Wil this work" - Have you tried?

Comment: if you'd run your code, you would have seen that it doesn't work and could have provided a - well, obvious - error message. question shows no effort on your own --> downvoted.

Comment: Thanx for your commends, I am a learner started to learn coding 2months ago,, i dnt know how to run a code, instead i am building the app, i am getting "unfortunately the app has closed "message. Please do not under estimate anyone, i hope stachoverflow can help me with this.

Comment: if i am commending out this line, everything is working, i know this line is causing issue, any help ???(**finalelement[i1]=element[i];**)

Comment: Please try to give your question a more catchy title: leave out the `[Will] this work, `, re-consider if the comparison or the type of element is crucial for your question. Try using a spelling checker.)

Comment: `finalelement[i1]=element[i];` _is causing issue_ - _how_ can it, what are the values of `finalelement`, `i1`, `element`, and `i`?

Comment: *i1* is *zero*, *finalelement* is a *null* array, can i assign value of element[i] to finalelement[i1],

Answer (score 1):

It's better to do it this way:

```
List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();
elements.add("France");
elements.add("Germany");
elements.add("USA");
elements.add("France");
elements.add("Italy");

List<String> finalElement = new ArrayList<>();
String compareElement = "France";

for (String str : elements) {
    if (compareElement.equals(str)) {
        finalElement.add(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is that?? What's the problem?

Comment: I was trying to store some other element of same index  from other array,, if the array of elements has the same entry... anyway, i have got the answer.. Posting below..

Answer (score 0):

At least the first line is wrong:
`String element={"France","Germany","USA","France","Italy"}`

```
String[] elements = new String[]{"France","Germany","USA","France","Italy"}
```

Comment: thankz @Назар Овчарчин,,,, help me with **finalelement[i1]=element[i];**

Comment: As Mohammad Z told you, it is better to use List, actually LinkedList will be good for you.